# Different Objective-C enums with the same literals

Tags: objective-c, enums

I wish to have two different `enum`s, but they might have the same literal; for example:

```
typedef enum {ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX} NumbersEnum;
typedef enum {ONE,TWO,THREE,FIVE,EIGHT} FibonacciEnum;
```

This will raise a compile error because `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`, `FIVE` are repeated in both `enum`s.

Is there a way to make this work as-is (not changing the literals' names or adding a prefix or suffix)?

Is there any way my code using the literals can look like this: `int num = NumbersEnum.SIX;` and not like this `int num = SIX;`?

Comment: Enumerations define sets of names, but you seem to want to use enumerations as containers. Objective-C and the Foundation framework provide a rich set of real containers -- why not try one?

Answer (score 1):

No. That's part of the C and Objective-C language from the beginning of time. You're not going to change it, and nobody is going to change it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `enum`s; their members are global and the names must be unique. There is, however, a neat technique you can use to [make pseudo-namespaces for constants](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-08-19-namespaced-constants-and-functions.html) with `struct`s.

Declare your "namespace" in the appropriate header:

```
extern const struct _FibonacciNumbers
{
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int five;
} FibonacciNumbers;
```

Then initialize the values in an implementation file:

```
const struct _FibonacciNumbers FibonacciNumbers = {
    .one = 1,
    .two = 2,
    .three = 3,
    .five = 5
};
```

You now access a constant as, e.g., `FibonacciNumbers.one`, and other `struct` types can use the same names since the names are private to each of them.

So that's "No" for your first option, but "Yes" to the second.

Comment: The precise examples you gave, though -- those two sets of numbers -- would be better implemented as simple arrays.

Comment: This example was just to clarify my question, if it was in real code I agree with your comment 100% it most definitely should be arrays :)

Comment: That's what I figured, and why I put that remark only in a comment rather than the answer.